# Issues with cosets and normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm having some issues with coset notation and how I'm supposed to work with them in the context of normal subgroups. I know that for $H \leq G$ we defined $gH = \{gh \mid h\in H\}$. But I seem to be misunderstanding what this means.

To illustrate this when we came to normal groups and we wanted to show that if $N$ is normal in $G$ then $\forall g \in G$ we have $gNg^{-1} \subset N$ I had thought to just say that if $Ng=gN$ then $gn=ng$ so $gng^{-1} = n \in N$ so $gNg^{-1} \in N$ however I've been told this is wrong, and you need to argue that there exists some $n' \in N$ such that $gn=n'g$ but why? If $N$ is normal why is it not that $ng=gn$ why are there two different elements of $N$?

Where is my understanding breaking down? I know it's a difficult question to ask but I don't understand the issue enough to specify what my problem is. Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me unpack this.

Comment: It's because normal subgroups are not necessarily abelian.

Comment: Do you know that the equality between two sets is shown by LHS$\subseteq$ RHS *and vice versa*?

Comment: Note that $gNg^{-1}\notin N$. You meant $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It being normal does not mean that individual elements automatically commute,  which is what you have,  $gn=ng$.   What it means instead is that $gN=Ng$.    Examining the notation,   $gN$ is the set of all elements that look like $g$ times some element of $N$.  Likewise, $Ng$ is the set of elements that look like some element of $N$ times $g$.   Saying they are equal means they are subsets of each other

So,  say $x\in gN$   That means there exists an element of $N$, call it $n_1$ such that $x=gn_1$.     Now since $gN=Ng$,  $x=gn_1\in Ng$.  So that means by definition there is some (possibly different) element of $N$, call it $n_2$  such that $$x=gn_1=n_2g$$

To move it to your form, we can right multiply by $g^{-1}$ to get

$$gn_1g^{-1}=n_2$$

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why it hadn't clicked in my mind that the elements of $N$ can be different!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A_4\lhd S_4$ while $A_4$ is not abelian.